# Fancybox 2 afterClose focus

Tags: callback, fancybox, focus, thumbnails, fancybox-2

I've just tried Fancybox 2 and have a problem!
In Fancybox 1.3.4 I could trigger a function when fancybox closed, namely to add the focus to the current thumb element (e.g. in a gallery).

It looked this way:

```
onClosed : function(){
 currentArray[currentIndex].focus();
}
```

However, in Fancybox 2 they deprecated `onClosed` and there is an other parameter, `afterClose`, but I couldn't find the variables that store the current thumb element.

Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
afterClose : function(){
 this.group[this.index].focus();
}
```

**EDIT** : The code above works for fancybox v2.0.6 and **below** (2.x) but not for fancybox 2.1.0+ (the cleanup process and some variables may have been modified).... so for fancybox v2.1.0 you need to get the selector from where fancybox was launched (`.fancybox` for instance) then, for this type of html

```
<a class="fancybox" ...
```

use the `beforeClose` option like:

```
beforeClose : function(){
 $(".fancybox").eq(this.index).focus();
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. TypeError: this.group[this.index].focus is not a function. Mabye the problem is that it doesn't get back a jquery element but a dom element. I can alert the current elements href like this: alert($(this.group[this.index]).attr('href')); but both of the class or the rel tag are undefined, although they are given...

Comment: @TóthAttila : you must be using v2.1.0 ... see my edited answer.

Comment: There is a small problem with this solution. I have some links on the site, that requires login before you can enter. So I have many fancybox links with the same href (login warning). The fancyboxes open perfectly, but after closing, all of them put the focus on the first "fancybox login link", not the one that opened the overlay.
Edit:
Sorry, I've just got the solution:
afterClose: function() {
    $(this.element).focus();
}